# In Windows 7, is there any way to pin a shortcut to the start menu or taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

In Windows 7, is there any way to pin a shortcut to the start menu or taskbar?

It appears if only programs can be pinned. I'd like to pin a shortcut to a program that specifies some arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can just right-click pinned item and select properties. There is textbox "Target". You can add arguments to there in the same way as with shortcuts.

Comment: Just note that you won't be able to pin different targets to the same application.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it from within File Explorer:

- Open File Explorer
- Navigate to the program you want
- Right Click the   program
- From the Pop Menu, Select Pin to Start Menu (or Taskbar)

Answer (score -1):

You can pin each program you like if you just pin them to the taskbar with right click on the icon "pin to taskbar". You can also pin each folder you like just make a shortcut with:
C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\Users\Username\Foldername

Answer (score -2):

You can drag and drop the shortcut to either the taskbar or the Start button.